# Do I need to add my framework to project again and again after editing ios?

Tags: ios, xcode, frameworks

I have my **own framework** which I've made. I use this framework in **another project** I made. That is, *after building my framework*, Dragged the Product, *.framework to Embedded Binaries* of **project**.

However, I've to *continuously make changes to the framework*. So the process of dragging and dropping **again and again** is a lot of work. How to conquer this ?
Can someone tell the **exact steps** even if it means including the project as well ?

Comment: Not a set of exact steps but idea.. You could create a script (bash or whatever) that replaces `.framework` at the locations you need from a predefined list (can be part of the script). That way, given that file name stays unchanged so Xcode projects have valid references, it probably should work. You just add new locations to the list whenever you need to use framework in a new project (don't forget to embed `.framework` initially), and then run script every time you have changes in framework to deploy changes.

Comment: What sort of a script to write in Build Phases? New to XCode here.

Comment: Since you want it to update multiple projects, I think you should store this script outside of the Xcode, just in your system. I'm assuming you use Mac, so you can write `bash` script to iterate through the locations of your framework in different Xcode projects, and replace it with your updated `.framework`. Something like `cp -f [oringinal file] [new file]` 

UPD: I'm not a bash guru you know, but I could try and write something as answer.

Comment: Yes please write this as an answer. Updating multiple projects having the same framework. I thought that was what a dynamic library would mean when I built a framework instead of a `.a` static lib.

Comment: I wrote, please check it out

Answer (score 2):

Copy the framework Project to your project folder.
Open your Project in xcode.
Right click on the Project File on left side of xcode and click on option "Add file to *Project Name*" and then select the framework project here.
Delete the Product .framework available in the embedded libraries and add the framework product properly.

Comment: I did the same, although how to add this framework properly :/ How would it solve my purpose of not building the .framework again  and again?

Comment: Add the framework in "Linked  framework and libraries" and check.

Comment: But when I include the `.framework project`(project F) in my project(project A), under Project F if i go to Products, the `.framework` product is in Red and doesn't generate.

Comment: Click '+' in "Linked framework and libraries" in project A and it will list the library files - in that select libF.a (F ---> framework Project name).

Answer (score 0):

So your goal is to 'deploy' changes made to `.framework` to all the projects you've already embedded it in previously. Here is one approach to it.

1. Create `[myFramework]Targets.txt` file where you'll be putting all the locations (directories) of your framework in different projects, line by line. It will have something like this:

   `~/Path/to/project/A/Frameworks
   ~/Path/to/project/B/Frameworks
   ~/Path/to/project/C/Frameworks`
2. Create `deploy_framework.sh` file with script that will replace your framework everywhere you need. I'm definitely not the one you can call a Bash expert, by here is what it probably looks like:

   `for destination in $(<[myFramework]Targets.txt); do /bin/cp -rf /Path/to/updated/[myFramework].framework "$destination"; done`
3. Now, whenever you're done with your framework changes, just run `deploy_framework.sh` from Terminal. Assuming your Xcode projects have existing reference to `.framework` and you didn't change its name, it should work.

**NOTE:** You might still need to do **Clean**+**Build** for your projects to compile with updated framework. I believe you can also tweak project settings to 'cache' builds less aggressively.

*Let me know if it works for you, we might need to adjust script a bit, since I never tested it.*